# How to replace a lot of nested ifs in validation process?

Tags: java, spring-boot, nested

I am handling response to a request, and I need to make sure that request is formed correctly and for different mistakes in a request I need to return different answers. I ended up doing nested ifs and after the third one I kinda feel that it looks quite messy and potentially buggy. So I came here to ask for an advice on how I can modify my code to avoid nested if statements.

Here is the code:

```
 public <T> ResponseEntity<T> validateRequest(Request request) {
        if(agentRepository.findAgentByRequestPoint(request.getPoint()).isPresent()){
            if(request.getAdvanced().getFunction().equals("CheckAcc")){
                if(ServiceRepository
.findServiceByServiceId(Long.parseLong(request.getAdvanced().getService()))
                        .isPresent()){
                    
                }else{
                    ResponseEntity.ok((T)  response.wrongCheck(1, 4);
                }
            }else{
                ResponseEntity.ok((T) response.wrongCheck(1, 1));
            }
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.ok((T)ErrorDTO.from(bundle.getString("point.not.set")));
        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make your code more readable is to split it into different methods:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> validateRequest(Request request) {
    if (!isAgentExists(request)) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok((T) ErrorDTO.from(bundle.getString("point.not.set")));
    }

    if (!isRequestFunctionCorrect(request, "CheckAcc")) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok((T) response.wrongCheck(1, 1));
    }

    if (!isServiceExists(request)) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok((T)  response.wrongCheck(1, 4);
    }

    // do the logic if everything is correct
}

private boolean isAgentExists(Request request) {
    return agentRepository.findAgentByRequestPoint(request.getPoint()).isPresent();
}

private boolean isRequestFunctionCorrect(Request request, String func) {
    if (request.getAdvanced() != null) {
        return func.equals(request.getAdvanced().getFunction());
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isServiceExists(Request request) {
    Long serviceId = Long.parseLong(request.getAdvanced().getService());
    return ServiceRepository.findServiceByServiceId(serviceName).isPresent()
}
```

In some cases I added additional null check to avoid NPE.

Hope it will helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public <T> ResponseEntity<T> validateRequest(Request request) {
  if(agentRepository.findAgentByRequestPoint(request.getPoint()).isEmpty())
    return ResponseEntity.ok((T)ErrorDTO.from(bundle.getString("point.not.set")));
    
  if(!request.getAdvanced().getFunction().equals("CheckAcc"))
    return ResponseEntity.ok((T) response.wrongCheck(1, 1));

  if(ServiceRepository.findServiceByServiceId(Long.parseLong(request.getAdvanced().getService())).isEmpty())
    return ResponseEntity.ok((T)  response.wrongCheck(1, 4));
}
```

I would suggest more validations or null checkings on the variables / methods, as some fields like `request.getAdvanced().getFunction().equals("CheckAcc")` or `request.getAdvanced().getService()` seems vulnerable to NPEs.

Or at least try catching the method and log stacktraces for future debugging purposes.

Hope it can help.